# Show a Facebox from a button click event

Tags: asp.net, jquery, facebox

The examples I have seen all show a Facebox by clicking on an anchor.  Is it possible to use a button instead?  I am modifying an asp.net page that dynamically generates asp:button controls, and would like to not have to replace them with anchors.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what "show a Facebook" means?  Do you have an example you could point us to?  I'm having trouble envisaging the outcome you're after.

Comment: He just wants to use a button instead of an anchor element to open a facebox window.  Facebox is a jQuery plugin that opens modal windows and has nothing to do with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this

jquery:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    $.facebox($('#save_name').html());
});
```

html:

```
<input id='save' type='button' class="facebox" value='Save Report' />

<div id="save_name" style="display:none" >
    <label>Report Name: </label>
    <input name="report_name" type="text" />
    <input id="save_report" type="button" value="Save" />       

</div>
```